# If $P(x)$ be a real polynomial such that $\lvert P(x)\rvert$ is also a polynomial then what can we conclude about $P(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

My thinking is this:-
If it is a constant polynomial then it is trivial. If it has degree $\geq 1$. Then the polynomial must be differentiable. Now for it to be differentiable it should lie totally on the upper half of the $xy-$ plane or the lower half . Well it can have roots,but we will consider to lie on the upper half or lower half regardless.

Considering geometrically, if the curve had a portion in the lower half and a portion on the upper half...then the function $\lvert P(x)\rvert$ would become non-differentiable at the root on account of it having "sharp edges" there.
Is my thinking correct? Did I miss anything? Can I conclude anything else?.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the polynomial and/or the variable $x$ complex ?

Comment: $|x|^3$ is differentiable everywhere, with continuous derivative, but not a polynomial.

Comment: @SolubleFish Real. Wait I'll edit it in.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes I know.... I am just mentioning the condition in the question. It is about $\lvert P(x)\rvert$ and not $\lvert\cdot\rvert^{n}$ . I guess I made a grammatical mistake. I meant to say P(x) is a polynomial such that modulus of it is also a polynomial.

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee Sorry, I typo'd slightly. If $P(x)=x^3$ then $|P(x)|$ is differentiabile everywhere with continuous derivative, including at the origin, but that still doesn't make it a polynomial.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Please see my edited comment

Comment: My point was more that you make the argument that 'if the curve had a portion in the lower half (-plane) and a portion in the upper half, then it would become nondifferentiable at the root'; the example I give is to show that that's not necessarily the case, so the argument you're making isn't enough.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I meant that if  the curve had a portion in the lower half (-plane) and a portion in the upper half, then the modulus of the polynomial would become non-differentiable. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $P(x)$ is positive at some point, then it's positive in an open interval, then $P(x) - |P(X)| $ is a polynomial with infinite zeros and must therefore be $0$, so $P(x)$ is always non-negative.

Assume $P(x)$ is negative at some point, then it's negative in an open interval, then $|P(x)| + P(x)$ is a polynomial with infinite zeros and must therefore be $0$, so $P(x)$ is always non-positive.

So the polynomials that work the ones that are always non-negative and the ones that are always non-positive.

Comment: Yes that's what I concluded from the differentiability perspective. Was my thinking correct? And is there anything else that we can conclude?

Comment: @Arghyadeep:  It may seem to you that Yorch is merely agreeing with your conclusion, but the proof technique used is subtly different than the incorrect differentiability argument you proposed.

Comment: Can you please explain where I went wrong with the differentiable argument?

Comment: *"...then the function |P(x)| would become non-differentiable at the root on account of it having "sharp edges" there."* as already pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @Randall The comment used $P(x)=x^{3}$ which is a polynomial true...but $\lvert P(x)\rvert$ is not a polynomial. But that does not matter as the question want's us to work with a polynomial such that $\lvert P(x)\rvert$ is also a polynomial. Is that the comment that you were referring to? . Otherwise are you saying that there exist some P(x) such that it has portions of the curve in both upper and lower halves and also $\lvert P(x)\rvert$ is a polynomial and also $\lvert P(x)\rvert$ is differentiable everywhere which would contradict my claim?

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee I'm not sure the differentiability directly excludes the possibility that $P$ is negative in $(-\infty,a)$ and $0$ In $(a,b)$ and positive in $(b,\infty)$. (Of course we know this isn't possible).

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee. By elementary means we can also show that if the polynomial $P:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is never negative then there is a finite set $R_1,...,R_m$ of polynomials such that $P=R_1^2+...+R_m^2.$

Comment: @Yorch thanks . That's where I went wrong. Anyways...your proof is really simple and excellent!! .